# Delete Amazon EBS volumes older than 60 days

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have written a code to find available volumes with no tags and then delete them but I would like to find a solution on how to delete only those volumes which are 60 days old.

```py
#! /usr/bin/python3.6

import boto3

ec2_object=boto3.resource(service_name='ec2',region_name='us-east-1')

all_required_volume_ids=[]

for each_vol in ec2_object.volumes.all():
    if each_vol.state=="available" and each_vol.tags==None:  
        print (each_vol.id, each_vol.state, each_vol.tags) 
        all_required_volume_ids.append(each_vol.id)

# Delete Volumes: Deleting the code

for each_vol in all_required_volume_ids:
    volume_ob = ec2_object.Volume(each_vol)
    print ("Deleting volume id" ,each_vol) 
    volume_ob.delete
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `create_time`:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Volume.create_time

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
now_minus_60days = now - datetime.timedelta(days=60)
print(now_minus_60days)
----extract the date part from now_minus_60days ------ 
if each_vol.create_time < now_minus_60days:
           delete the volume
```

Comment: I tried create_time but it didnt work for me . I used below logic just to print and see 
for each_vol in ec2_object.volumes.all():
        if each_vol.state=="available" and each_vol.tags==None:
           while True:
                 start_time = each_vol.create_time
                 delete_time = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=90)
                 if delete_time > start_time:
                     print ('fmt_start_time = {} And delete_time = {}'.format(start_time,delete_time))

Comment: Added some pseudo-code.